# How to get WindowsPrincipal from username and password

Tags: c#, basic-authentication

I am using WebAPI and hosting it with Katana. I'm writing some middleware right now that will be used for authentication and authorization. I have to use basic authentication with SSL because requests could be coming from a variety of platforms. OAuth is also not an option at this time. The middleware needs to take the username and password provided from basic authentication and validate that the user is a member in a local Windows Group.

Right now I am trying to figure out how to create a WindowsPrincipal. If I could figure how to create a WindowsPrincipal from a username and password I know how to do the rest. Here is what I have right now.

```
    //TODO
    WindowsPrincipal userPrincipal = null; //This is where I need to take the username and password and create a WindowsPrincipal
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = userPrincipal;

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
    PrincipalPermission permission = new PrincipalPermission(null, "Local Group Name");
    permission.Demand();
```

I am struggling to find a good way to use the username and password to validate that the member is part of a specific group. What is the best way to do this? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I think that you should be using a WindowsIdentity instead of the WindowsPrincipal to get that infromation.

To aquire/impersonate the user you must p/invoke LogonUser() from the advapi32.dll:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(
        string lpszUsername,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        out IntPtr phToken);
```

Considering that the above is in the class "Native", impersonating the user would be as following:

```
var userToken = IntPtr.Zero;

var success = Native.LogonUser(
  "username", 
  "domain", 
  "password", 
  2, // LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE
  0, // LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT
  out userToken);

if (!success)
{
  throw new SecurityException("User logon failed");
}

var identity = new WindowsIdentity(userToken);

if(identity.Groups.Any(x => x.Value == "Group ID")) 
{
    // seems to be in the group!
}
```

You can find additional information about the native call here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: By the way if you still need access to the WindowsPrincipal, you can generate it out of the WindowsIdentity: WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for the help! One last question about this approach. I don't have much experience calling native code from managed code and want to make sure that I cleanup all unmanaged resources. It looks like I should close the handle for the userToken when done with CloseHandle() in kernel32.dll. Is there anything else that I should cleanup related to the native call that I am missing?

Comment: Actually you don't have to do anything else then to call CloseHandle() once you don't need the user token anymore. I believe that the lifetime of the WindowsIdentity isn't bound to the lifetime of the token, but you might want to try that on your own!